# Algorithm for best Reputation League

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I always wondered on what algorihm the best league of mine is chosen.

[image: league]

I am in the **0.16% of this quarter**. That is rank 171 this quarter. But I am also ranked 113th this month.

Why is the stat for the quarter displayed when I have a better ranking in the month?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

```
quarter: 171th of 108499 ==> 0.1576%
month:   113th of 39822  ==> 0.2837%
```

And the reputation league shows the best one. So in this case, you have a better classification percentage in the quarter league although in the absolute classification you are higher in the list.

Update: as you show in comments, note that *users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues*. So that is one of the reasons of having different amount of users ranked for every league.

Comment: So in the leagues a different number of people are listed. Interesting. Haven't thought of that.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Note that it takes into account people scoring >=200 in that period. So the bigger the period is, the more people can be considered. Put it to the limit: if it was just one day, there would be just a few people; if it was all lifetime, it would even consider people answering three years ago for just one week.

Comment: Ah, I see it now: *users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues*